# How can I buffer a radio stream in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, avplayer

I have an avplayer which plays an online radio stream, and I want to buffer the stream locally so if the connection is lost the playback should continue for the buffer length.

Should I download the playlist file using a download task ?